# How to change the shop background color in Hestia Pro WordPress Theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to change the background color of Shop page only, www.momen-taste.at to a darker grey, but haven't managed to accomplish that. I am using the Hestia Pro WordPress theme.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Every page has unique class name, so as your shop page too must have the unique class name. Pick the unique class name and target the element for which you want to change the background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS class used in your shop to define the background is different from the other pages.

Hence, all you have to do is define the background color of the CSS class of your shop.

Add the following code in your child theme or custom CSS box:

```
.woocommerce.archive .main {
    background-color: #f0f0f0; /* Hex code of the color of your choice */
}
```

This should do the job.

Hope this helps.